# Implementing inequality join in hive from mysql query

Tags: mysql, hive, hiveql, inequality

I am trying to implement a query in hive which was written in mysql. I know that hive doesn't support the inequality joins on ON condition. Below is my code and tell me a way to implement it.

```
Select test1.a,
test2.b,
test4.c,
dummy.c
from
test1 join test2 on test1.id = test2.id and test2 != 'ABC'
join test3 on test1.id = test2.id and test3 != 'Archive'
join test4 on test3.id = test4.id and test4 = 'XYZ'
left outer join
(select test1.a,
test2,b
test3.c
from test1 join test2 on test1.id = test2.id and test2 != 'ABC'
join test3 on test1.id = test2.id) dummy
on test3.id = dummy.id
**and (test4.id != 1001 or dummy.c = TRUE)**
left join test5 on test3.id= test5.id
and dummy.c = TRUE
```

Now the condition highlighted with * is the part where I need to know how to implement it in hive because I cannot implement it at ON condition and if I am putting it in where clause results are not matching.
Any suggestions to rewrite it in hive would be appreciated.

Comment: You have to create a temporary table for dummy inner query and inequality should be in where clause of that query and then do the join with this temporary table instead of dummy.

Comment: @AbhinavSingh I want to implement it without creating temporary table.

Comment: I am trying to understand the requirements of your query and the data. You are not pulling any column from Dummy table but still doing left join with it. So, just want to clear whether you are looking for UNION ALL or Left Join in your query?

Comment: @AbhinavSingh In fact I am selecting 2-3 columns from the dummy table. I just added once column in the select statement.

Comment: @AbhinavSingh Thanks for looking into this. I solved it. I used the inequality condition in the final select statement for the records coming from left join and it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the inequality condition as a case statement in my SELECT statement for the columns which are being selected from the LEFT JOIN .
Below is the code -

```
Select test1.a,
test2.b,
test4.c,
case when (test4.id != 1001 or nvl(dummy.c , False))= TRUE then dummy.c end as c0
from
test1 join test2 on test1.id = test2.id and test2 != 'ABC'
join test3 on test1.id = test2.id and test3 != 'Archive'
join test4 on test3.id = test4.id and test4 = 'XYZ'
left outer join
(select test1.a,
test2,b
test3.c
from test1 join test2 on test1.id = test2.id and test2 != 'ABC'
join test3 on test1.id = test2.id) dummy
on test3.id = dummy.id
left join test5 on test3.id= test5.id
and dummy.c = TRUE
```